# Bootstrap 3 | Content in column pushes other column down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

So i tried to create a content box with two side boxes in bootstrap and i ran into this problem.

If the content in my big content box is too long it pushes down the second side box.

I'm using plain Bootstrap 3 without custom grid styling.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-8">
</div>

<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
</div>

<div class="col-md-offset-9 col-md-3">
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Here are two Screenshots to visualize what my goals are and what i'm actually getting.

[My goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm3Gl.png)

[What i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJBIB.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's grid units are based on percentages. Each unit is 8.33% wide (1/12th of 100%). Your first two `div.col`s add up to 100% width:

`.col-md-8` = 66.67%

`.col-md-offset-1.col-md-3` = 8.33% + 25%

66.67 + 8.33 + 25 = 100%

This is why your third `div.col` wraps to a new 'row'.

Because [columns can be nested](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting), this is how I would solve your problem:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
      <div class="row">
       </div class="col-xs-12"></div>
       </div class="col-xs-12"></div>
      </div><!-- .row -->
    </div><!-- .col -->
  </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```